# Contract is deployable on Remix Ethereum only with "Enable optimization"

Tags: gas, out-of-gas

my contract is only deployable to a blockchain via remix Ethereum as soon as I enable optimization. Otherwise it runs out of gas before deployment. Is there anyway to include this optimization in my code? Because I would like to use truffle building a DAPP with this code.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable optimization with Truffle as well, and also increase the gas limit. Use the following truffle.js file:

```
 module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gas: 4500000
    }
  },
  solc: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 200
    }
  }
};
```